# How to submit a form by appending textbox value to URL in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a HTML form containing a textbox and a submit button. When I submit the form, I want textbox value appending to the URL.

For example, if my domain is http://www.example.com/ and form lies on index.php. Suppose textbox value is "test" then when the form is submitted the URL should change to http://www.example.com/test. How can we achieve it?

**HTML Code:**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="txtname" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
$name = NULL;

if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit']))
{
    $name = $_POST["txtname"];
}
?>
```

**.htaccess Code:**

```
# .htaccess mod_rewrite
# example.com

#Enable mod rewrite
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What's the point of such approach?

Comment: @u_mulder An approximation of Wikipedia's "go to article" box maybe? But in such a situation, it's best to submit the form and have the server then redirect you to the correct page if it exists, or a helpful error page if not...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you guessed but it was not that.

Comment: @u_mulder I want to do it because I want to share the URL with textbox value in SEO friendly way and NOT with GET query string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use header:

```
$name = $_POST['txtname'];
header('Location: http://www.example.com/$name');
```

If you want to get the value without the error you can set the variable to empty like this:

```
$name = isset($_POST['txtname']) ? $_POST['txtname'] : '';
```

Place that after your opening php tag.

Comment: But I don't want to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

How about a jQuery solution? Something like...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var txtname = $('#txtname').val();
 var url = window.location.href;
 var new_url = url + "/" + txtname;
  
 $('#formid').on('submit', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   // Do what you need to do here.
   console.log(new_url);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formid" method="post" action="">
  <input id="txtname" type="text" name="txtname" value="testname" />
 <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: But the form textbox value is not received by the page. I want to retain the submitted value in the textbox as well. I'm getting `Notice: Undefined index: txtname in ...` when I try to receive textbox value via PHP.

Comment: If you're getting that error you need to set your textname variable before the post submit. Refer to my edited answer above.